# How to debug lua script in a unity project?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, lua, ide

We are embedding lua scripts into a unity project, but getting no IDE to debug.
Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you embedding? Does unity provide any means to debug Lua whatsoever? *Can you `print`?*

Comment: `LuaState ls = new LuaState(); ls.DoString(luaStr);`  We are using `ulua` plugin.. And unity has not provide any debugger.

Comment: You should use Lua Studio. The KopiLuaDebug project, which is mentioned in To Paul Kulchenko's answer, does not contain unity engine and will crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [KopiLuaDebug](https://github.com/gfoot/kopiluadebug) project that provides debugging capabilities for Lua scripts in Unity3d and integrates with [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com), although I'm not sure if it works with uLua. I've also seen [posts on using ZeroBrane Studio to debug uLua](https://www.freelists.org/post/zerobrane/Unity3D-expand-tables-in-Watch-and-luaL-dostring), but don't have any further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio as your IDE, you can try [babelua](https://babelua.codeplex.com/)